# How can I get the values between two relational operation from an image

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, relationship

I'm trying to obtain the values between two relational operation from an image.

`A(34,67,4)` is an image with the given values.
I need the values of `A` between 0 and 16 (`0<=A<=16`).

When I tried to do it as follows, this just gave me 0 or 1 (not values of `A` array). Could you tell me What the problem is?

```
B=((A<=0)&(A>=16)+((A>=0)&(A<=16))
```

Comment: Do you just want the values that satisfy that condition? Or do you want to keep the matrix structure, and set all elements that do not satisfy that condition to 0 or something?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep matrix structure to find the values satisfy this condition.

Comment: And what will the other elements in the structure then be? Look at the 2nd part of my solution, and see if that suits your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to apply the condition

```
(A>=0)&(A<=16)
```

as [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html) on the matrix `A`:

```
B = A(A>=0 & A<=16);
```

This'll render you a vector of values, because it selects only those values that satisfy your condition, and because they can occur anywhere in the matrix, there is no structure to return them to you but in a vector.

If you however want to keep the matrix, and reset every value that does not satisfy the condition the 0 or `NaN` (so everything that's left is all the elements that do satisfy the condition) use the following:

```
B = A;
B(A<0 | A>16) = NaN;
```

If you also want to apply an operation to those values (and those values only, not the NaN's), you can do it as follows:

```
B = A;
select_idx = A>=0 & A<=16;
B(~select_idx) = NaN;
B( select_idx) = arrayfun(@myfun, B(select_idx) );
```

For example:

```
A = rand(10)*30-5
B = A;
select_idx = A>=0 & A<=16;
B(~select_idx) = NaN;
B( select_idx) = arrayfun(@floor, B(select_idx) );
```

It'll set all values outside the range 0-16 to NaN, and apply the floor function on all values inside the range.

Comment: Thank you Gunther Struyf, the second code gave me the matrix structure. But I'm worried about when I calculate an equation using the array with NaN value (B in our example), whether NaN values will return to real integer values or not. According to my test, output from an equation still keep the NaN values. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do with the values: it looks like you want to apply a function on values in a matrix satisfying a condition. That changes your question of course... On a sidenote: you can apply a arithmetic operation on NaN values, they just stay NaN. Check my edited answer for yet another approach

Comment: Thanks again. You understood correctly that I want to apply a function on all values in matrix satisfying this condition (0 and 16). I asked it wrongly. Sorry for that. There is another question I wanna ask from you. Is it possible to get values within the range of 0 and 16 from each band of image. My image size is A(35,76,7). Also expected output should be the same size with A (with 7 band). I'm asking this question not to repeat the same process on separate bands again and again.

Comment: have you tried this out already? cause then you would have noticed that the code I gave works for any-dimensional matrices

Comment: Yes, I have. But That was on single band image. Just now I tried it on a multiband image. You're right, It can work on any-dimensional matrices. Generally, every time when I calculate arithmetic operation on any-dimensional matrices, what kind of syntax (or code) should I always write in order to keep matrix structure. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: b=0.0001*((a<=0)&(a>=16))+a*((a>=16)&(a<=16)); Can it be another way to get value between this range? I've just tried this. It gave me the value between this range without NaN value.

Comment: yes, but that'll be slower, the parts with logical operators (eg `(a<=0)&(a>=16)`) converts the matrix to logical values (true/false or 0/1). If you apply an arithmetic operation (eg `a*((a>=16)&(a<=16))`) on that, it will convert back to double. That statement you have there will thus put 0.0001 where `(a<=0)&(a>=16)` and `a` itself where `(a>=16)&(a<=16)`. Directly accesing/selecting the elements with indexing is of course faster (and better imo, since you don't have the unnessecary conversion double->logical->double)

Comment: For keeping matrix structure: in general just apply operations on the whole matrix: `B = A*4;` OR for operations on a submatrix: select elements of the matrix and put them back on the same place with indexing: `A(5:6,:) = 4*A(5:6,:);`